Store all option labels from a drop-down list in a variable in webdriverio
I would like to store all labels from a drop-down list in a variable and compare with another variable thanks to WEBDRIVERIO.
I tried this but it's failing:
// Locate the select element
const selectElement = await $('//select[@name="myDropDown"]');

const optionTexts ='';

selectElement.forEach((element) => {
    optionTexts = element.getText();
});

I tried this also but it's not working:
selectElement .map(option => option.getText());

This code is not working too with the error: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)):
const dropdown = await $('//select[@name="fdYearFilter"]'); 

// Retrieve all the option elements within the drop-down
const options = await dropdown.$$('option');

// Extract the text of each option and store in an array
const optionTexts = await Promise.all(options.map(async (option) => {
return await option.getText();
}));

Could you please help me with that ?
Thanks for your help.
